# Radiobutton in instances of Django ModelChoiceField

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I am trying to manually render a ModelChoiceField with instances in the template. This is working ok, but I am not able to add the radio button in the last cell. How do I do add the radio button ?

forms.py:

```
class SubmissionForm(forms.Form):
      name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
      spl_candidates = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Candidate.objects.filter(category="SPL"),
                                        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
                                        empty_label=None)
```

Template

```
    <table>
        {% for data in form.spl_candidates.field.queryset %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ data.name }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ data.description }}
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom HTML radio button to achieve this,

In Your **Template** do this,

```
    <table>
    {% for data in form.spl_candidates.field.queryset %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ data.name }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ data.description }}
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="{{ data.name }}" value="{{ data.desc }}">
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: It does shows the radio button but it can select all them together, that's not the normal behavior of a radio select widget :P

Comment: The unique identifier for the radio button is `name` attribute whenever your loop iterates a new `{{ data.name }}` will come, so you wont get a chance to select all of them together.